# get element count with a few parameters angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter elements using angular's filter to check on 2 attributes and then get the number of returned elements

this is what i have tried:

```
$scope.countPriorityActive = true;
$scope.getCountActive = function(strCat) {
    return filterFilterActive($scope.tasks, {priority: strCat, active: true}).length;
};
```

but it's not working
I have started by editing this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8YbRTd?p=preview
what's my mistake?

Comment: what does filterFilterActive do?

Comment: @valepu it should return element length

Comment: it's working in the plunkr. If i add console.log(filterFilter( $scope.heroes, {comic:strCat}).length); to the getCount function i can see the returned results. In the plunkr it's written "filterFilter" though

Comment: @valepu, I try add 1 more value to value count, but wit 2 values it's not working

Comment: No comic has the attribute "active" in the list in the plunkr. if i add "active: true" on a comic it correctly counts it

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4fisDO?p=preview

Comment: @valepu it's my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add the "active" attribute in the elements of your array

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Iron Man',
  fname: 'Tony',
  lname: 'Stark',
  location: 'Stark Tower',
  comic: 'Marvel'
  active: true //this is what you need to add to each element
},
```

also you need to call "filterFilter", not "filterFilterActive" unless you made a new filter yourself